# Add a 2nd header to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2], 'col2':[3,4], 'col3':[5,6], 'col4':[7,8], 'col5':[9,10]})
```

and would like to add a second header to it such that col1, col2 and col3 go under header1 and col4 and col5 go under header2, so instead of this

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
 0   1    3      5     7    9
 1   2    4      6     8    10
```

I would like to have this

```
  header1            header2
  col1   col2  col3  col4  col5
 0   1    3      5     7    9
 1   2    4      6     8    10
```

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you can create a list, e.g., `level_0 = ['header1','header1','header1','header2','header2']` and then use `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level_0, df.columns])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1':[1,2], 'col2':[3,4], 'col3':[5,6], 'col4':[7,8], 'col5':[9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('header1', 'col1'), ('header1', 'col2'), ('header1', 'col3'), ('header2', 'col4'), ('header2', 'col5')])
df.columns = columns
print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the `MultiIndex` function provided by pandas.
For example you could try `MultiIndex.from_arrays`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2], 'col2':[3,4], 'col3':[5,6], 'col4':[7,8], 'col5':[9,10]})
header1 = ['header1'] *3
header2 = ['header2'] *2
new_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([header1 + header2, df.columns])
df.columns = new_columns
```

This will get you what you expect.